# "Global trade is carried by sea"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Is this sentence grammatically correct? And why?

> about 80% of global trade is carried by sea, and estimates of the volume carried through the South China Sea range from 20% to 33%

I am not sure about the "global trade is carried"

Comment: In most contexts, ***[global] trade*** refers to the *process* of selling goods [around the world]. But for lack of any obvious concise alternative, in the cited context above, ***trade = goods** [which are traded]*. Some people might prefer *...global trade is carried **out*** (i.e. - the ***activity*** is ***performed*** via seaways, as opposed to the ***goods*** being ***transported***). But I'd say that's just pointless pedantry. The cited text sounds fine to me.

Comment: The full OED has **trade** definition IV-15: *Commodities for use in bartering, esp. with indigenous peoples*, where one cited instance is 1884  (Pall Mall Budget 22 Aug) *One of these boats has on board the ‘trade’, as we call the goods by which purchases are effected.* I wouldn't really say the cited usage reflects that definition, though.

Comment: Your comments are really good as answers! Why not post them as answers @FumbleFingers?

Comment: That's just my take. Others may think different, and/or they might be able to cite an actual current dictionary definition matching this example (the best I could find was that OED definition, which obviously doesn't *really* match your context).

Comment: I find this question somewhat interesting because it is not entirely clear whether "by" indicates the verb's "agent" (as it usually does with passive constructions) or not. It depends on how you define "carry".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Trade" means to exchange goods. Like, "I will trade you my orange for your apple." On a larger scale, it can mean the exchange of goods between regions or countries. Like, "Japan trades automobiles and other manufactured goods for raw materials like oil and steel." "Global trade" means trade on the scale of the entire world. i.e. we're talking about all the goods bought and sold by every country in the world, or at least by many countries.

If countries are trading goods, they have to be transported from one country to another somehow. They might be carried by truck or train, or by airplane, or by camel, or whatever. One way to transport goods is in boats. So "carried by sea", meaning carried from one country to another over the sea in boats.